# How can I compute covariances between parameters in WinBUGS?

Tags: covariance-matrix, bugs

I am wondering if there is an easy way to compute the covariances between parameters in WinBUGS/OpenBUGS. It is easy to obtain the variances, but for subsequent analysis, I need the covariances. Consider the Salm example:

```
model
{
    for( i in 1 : doses ) {
        for( j in 1 : plates ) {
            y[i , j] ~ dpois(mu[i , j])
            log(mu[i , j]) <- alpha + beta * log(x[i] + 10) + 
                gamma * x[i] + lambda[i , j]
            lambda[i , j] ~ dnorm(0.0, tau) 
            cumulative.y[i , j] <- cumulative(y[i , j], y[i , j])
        }
    }
    alpha ~ dnorm(0.0,1.0E-6)
    beta ~ dnorm(0.0,1.0E-6)
    gamma ~ dnorm(0.0,1.0E-6)
    tau ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)
    sigma <- 1 / sqrt(tau)
}
```

How would you obtain the covariance between alpha and beta? Alternately, is there anyway to save the last 1000 iterations and then manually compute the variances outside?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the correlation between alpha and beta under "Inference > Correlation Tool"; multiply this correlation with standard deviations from "Inference > Samples"